# azure pipeline to check if file is present inside a folder

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have 3 folders inside a folder called "prod" namely:
123,234,456

I have to list all the folders inside "prod" folder and check if "file-acknowledgement.ack" file is present in all folders(123,234,456 in this case) , if not present then wait until the file is present in all folders.
else go ahead to next stage if file is present in all folders.

how to do it using azure data factory

Answer (score 0):

You can use get meta data activity to check whether files present within a folder location.

Have this within an Until activity and continue the iteration till the files are present in all 3 folders.

So the flow would be :
a) untill activity

within it:
a) get meta data activities (3: one for each folder)
b) use If activity to chcek whether the required file for all 3 folder exist.
c) if not then wait activity else Set a variable as success

use the variable : if success to exit the until activity

1. Create a parameterized dataset :
   [image]
2. create a variable called 'OverallStatus'
3. use a until activity with expression as below:
   @equals(variables('OverallStatus'),'Done' )
4. within until activity have 3 getmetadata activities in parallel with below configs:

[image]

provide the path name and file name

[image]

5. use IF activity :
   [image]

expression :
@and(activity('Folder1').output.exists,and(activity('Folder2').output.exists,activity('Folder3').output.exists))

If all 3 files exist, use Set variable activity within TRUE condition:
[image]

else use WAIT activity

[image]

Comment: thanks for your comment, helps a lot. do u have any pipeline which i can refer to

Comment: hey @karthikkk, I have edited the answer with details